# Git usa rebase en vez de fast-forward y merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull, git-rebase

Llevo unos días con problemas para trabajar con git y no encuentro solución ni alguien que tenga un problema similar.
La cuestión es la siguiente:

- Tengo git instalado en mi pc y en una MV en citrix. Cuando hago un `git pull` de una rama a la mia en citrix, git usa *merge by recursive strategy*. Desde que empecé a usar la MV no me dio problema ninguno.
- Ahora que ya trabajo en local, ya que la máquina me va algo lenta, al hacer `git pull` de una rama a la mía, git usa `rebase` en vez de `merge` como la MV en citrix. Y se hace todo bastante lioso y con muchos problemas a la hora de hacer el pull.
  -En internet no encontré nada al respecto, solo información de cuándo usar uno u otro y por qué. Probé a revisar las configuraciones de git de vscode por si causaba algún conflicto. Reinstalé git y vi que en la instalación hay un proceso de configuración donde puedes elegir entre *rebase*, *merge fast-forward* u otra opción que no recuerdo. Ayer lo reinstalé y me fijé mucho en marcar la opción del *merge*. Todo funcionó perfecto hasta hoy, que volví a hacer un pull para traerme los cambios que habian hecho mis compañeros y git se empeña en hacer *rebase*. Volví a reinstalarlo y marcar la misma opción pero esta vez ya hace el *rebase* de primeras cuando no debería de estar así configurado.
- Mi solución actual está siendo crear la rama en la MV y después de hacer todos los pull que necesito, la traigo a local y trabajo con ella. Pero es una solución muy poco práctica al tener que estar cambiando continuamente de local a MV al querer hacer pull de una rama.

¿Alguien tiene una idea de cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: Git guarda sus opciones en dos lugares. Basta que los revises y modifiques a tu conveniencia. No necesitas reinstalar todo cada vez. El primer lugar es el propio repositorio local. Ese repositorio tiene una carpeta llamada .git y dentro de ella un archivo config. Editalo y mira si es ahi donde tienes opciones bajo `[pull]`. El otro sitio donde debes mirar es en tu carpeta de usuario, el fichero `.gitconfig`

Comment: El `~/.gitconfig` es el de las opciones globales. El `config` dentro del `.git` del repositorio es el de las opciones locales. Las locales tienen precedencia sobre las globales. Puede ser que se haya cambiado la opción `[pull]` localmente, por lo que por mucho que reinstales git no servirá de nada, pues la opción local (que puede ser la estrategia rebase) prevalece sobre la global (que puede ser la estrategia merge)

Comment: Muchas gracias a los dos! La configuración a nivel usuario estaba con rebase=true. Ahora a parte de solucionar el problema ya sé un poco mas sobre git. Muchas gracias y un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias cuestiones, la solución al problema más puntual, tipo "hotfix", sería usar el comando `git pull --no-rebase`, lo cual te va a permitir saltear la configuración que tengas.

En segundo lugar, deberías poder encontrar dónde está esa configuración que te está molestando, que en este caso es `pull.rebase` o `branch.<name>.rebase` en alguno de los archivos de configuración de git.

Por último, está la cuestión de adaptar el flujo de trabajo para usar `pull.rebase` lo cual tiene una serie de ventajas importantes y es a mi criterio lo más recomendable.

El cambio del flujo de trabajo tiene que ver con simplemente no trabajar directamente en las ramas *compartidas*, si no, utilizar siempre ramas de desarrollo locales para el trabajo propio. De esta manera se minimiza la cantidad de *merges* y se simplifica mucho la historia, cosa que a la larga permite corregir con mayor facilidad las regresiones.